# quotes inside quotes with windows' cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line

I have the following command set as a custom URL protocol in windows registry:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "SET r=%1 & SET s=!r:jhvnc:=! & start C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe !s:_= !"
```

This is not working because the path to the exe file has a space.

Normally, I'd use quotes:

```
cmd /V:ON /C "SET r=%1 & SET s=!r:jhvnc:=! & start "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" !s:_= !"
```

but the command is already in quotes. I tried escaping the quotes with double quotes, but that did not work.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest top open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `start /?` and read the output help. The first `"` quoted argument string is interpreted by the command __START__ as optional title for the console window. In your case is started a Windows GUI application and for that reason no console window is opened at all by the Windows library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) used by `explorer.exe` to start `cmd.exe` and by `cmd.exe` to start `vncviewer.exe`.

Comment: The general solution is using after command `start` first `""` to specify an empty window title on starting a Windows GUI application to get `"C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe"` interpreted as executable with full qualified file name enclosed in `"` by the command __START__. I recommend to run next `cmd /?` and read the output help very carefully. It would be good to reference `cmd` with its full qualified file name, use additionally the options `/D` and `/E:ON` and use explicitly the option `/S`.

Comment: So in registry should be defined the string value with: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /D /E:ON /V:ON /S /C "set "r=%~1" & set "s=!r:jhvnc:=!" & start "" "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" "!s:_= !""`

Comment: The command(s) after /C does not need quotes

Comment: The only problematic part in Mofi's suggestion is `%~1`, which appears unquoted, potentially leading to errors when it contains special characters; the only reliable way is most likely this: `%ComSpec% /D /E:ON /V:ON /S /C ^"set "r=%~1" ^& set "s=!r:jhvnc:=!" ^& start "" "C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" "!s:_= !"^"` (with the outer-most quotes escaped, hence letting `%~1` appear quoted)

Comment: @Anders, removing quotes leads to the need of escaping of every special character…

Answer (score 0):

Simplest work around is use the historic short folder name

That should be C:\PROGRA~1\UVNCBV~1\

check using dir /x /a:d C:\PROGRA~1\U*

```
cmd /V:ON /C "SET r=%1 & SET s=!r:jhvnc:=! & start C:\PROGRA~1\UVNCBV~1\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe !s:_= !"
```

Comment: Short name generation can be turned off in the OS or per volume.